# Issue regarding Magento 2 admin url

Tags: runtime-error, admin, magento2

I recently installed Magento on XAMPP. However my admin link that it provided after setup is giving me the error (in image attached)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xpnM.png)

My admin url: http://localhost:8080/magento/store1/admin_5jmzue

Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: Invalid URL try this (http://localhost:8080/magento/admin_5jmzue) or open this file (app/etc/env.php) you will find back-end url frontname:

```
'backend' => [
    'frontName' => 'admin_5jmzue'
]
```

Case 2: Check you server configurations if mode re-write is enabled.